# Unable to Run Karate Tests

Tags: karate

I am unable to run the karate tests in my feature

```
package api;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Karate.class)
public class PagesRunner {
}
```

[this is the report which gets generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2nyY.png)

My Feature file:

```
Feature: some Adaptor Request Success

Background:
* def myUrl = baseURL
* configure headers = read('classpath:some-headers.js')
Scenario: Some Adaptor Success
* def someInitiate= read('classpath:requests/someRequest.json')
* url myUrl
Given path 'api/somerequest'
And request someInitiate
When method post
Then status 202
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Very new to api automation world. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When I run the feature file directly, I get this error :1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
8 Steps (8 undefined)

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you follow the quick-start example to get started.

https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.intuit.karate \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=karate-archetype \
-DarchetypeVersion=0.8.0 \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany \
-DartifactId=myproject
```

Then try to run the `UsersRunner.java` | `users.feature` without issues. Then you can build on that.

Comment: Hi @Peter, Thanks for your response. I use gradle as my build tool. This is what I have in my gradle build file. Not sure what I am missing here.. `testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:0.8.0'
    testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-junit4:0.8.0'
    testCompile 'com.intuit.karate:karate-core:0.8.0'

Comment: @Madhusudhan sorry I can't help you with Gradle. see if this helps you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/463#issuecomment-406599694

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste below to your pom.xml file after  and reload.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my problem:

```
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).